# Remove last \" from link with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Next link example returns 2 links both end with **\"**. There are no links end with \" in the example text. But I get this when I run below preg_match_all() function in a WordPress site.

I need to fix this and get only links **NOT** end with  \"

Here the text example where I retrieve the links from:

```
$banner_link = '[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJIOI.gif" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="" />][2]
```

';

```
preg_match_all('!https?://\S+!', $banner_link, $matches);
$all_urls = $matches[0];
print_r($all_urls[0]); 
echo '<br>';
print_r($all_urls[1]);
```

Here the result both end with \"

> https://mobico.nl/telefoon/?tt=26156_1144596_250041_&r=\"
>
> http://ti.tradetracker.net/?c=26156&m=1144596&a=250041&r=&t=html\"

I can do it with a str_replace() but probably it is possible with the preg_match_all() function.

Comment: your `$banner_link` doesn't contain `\`, edit your input data

Comment: dont understand what you mean.

Comment: There is no `\"` after `r=` in the input string. The URLS identified by `preg_match_all()` end with `"` because the `regex` is too permissive.

Comment: just add some extra info. Read thread again please, I think WordPress is causing this issue. But i need to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no `\"` after `r=` in the input string, there is no way `preg_match_all()` returns URLs that end with `\"`.

The URLS identified by `preg_match_all()` end with `"` because the `regex` is too permissive.

Try this one:

```
$banner_link = '<a href="https://mobico.nl/telefoon/?tt=26156_1144596_250041_&amp;r=" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://ti.tradetracker.net/?c=26156&amp;m=1144596&amp;a=250041&amp;r=&amp;t=html" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="" /></a>';

preg_match_all('!https?://[^"]*!', $banner_link, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://mobico.nl/telefoon/?tt=26156_1144596_250041_&amp;r=
            [1] => http://ti.tradetracker.net/?c=26156&amp;m=1144596&amp;a=250041&amp;r=&amp;t=html
        )
)
```

Comment: It still ends now each link with a  \  Maybe WP does this.
I solved this till now with $link1 =  str_replace('\', '', $matches[0] );